# Extracting two, rather than four, digit year from datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am using the following code to create a new time variable in a pandas dataframe from a datetime object:

```
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data['Year'] = data['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
data['Month'] = data['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
data['Day'] = data['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
data['time'] = data['Month'].map(str) + '/' + data['Day'].map(str)  
+'/'+ data['Year'].map(str)
data = data.drop(["Date", 'Year','Month',"Day"], axis=1)
```

Which produces the following 'time' column:

```
 0         2/4/2016
 1        8/16/2016
 2        9/28/2016
 3        9/29/2016
 4        10/5/2016
```

I would like the output to be like this instead:

```
0         2/4/16
1        8/16/16
2        9/28/16
3        9/29/16
4        10/5/16
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the date accessor with `strftime`: [**`pd.Series.dt.strftime`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)
Refer to [**http://strftime.org/**](http://strftime.org/) for codes you can use.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Date=pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=5)))
df

        Date
0 2017-01-01
1 2017-01-02
2 2017-01-03
3 2017-01-04
4 2017-01-05
```

Then

```
df['time'] = df.Date.dt.strftime('%-m/%-d/%y')

df

        Date    time
0 2017-01-01  1/1/17
1 2017-01-02  1/2/17
2 2017-01-03  1/3/17
3 2017-01-04  1/4/17
4 2017-01-05  1/5/17
```

Comment: @GrahamStreich Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by changing the lambda function acting on the **Year column**.

```
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])

data['Year'] = data['Date'].apply(lambda x: str(x.year)[-2:]) #Last two characters of year

data['Month'] = data['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
data['Day'] = data['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
data['time'] = data['Month'].map(str) + '/' + data['Day'].map(str) +'/'+ data['Year'].map(str)[2:]
data = data.drop(["Date", 'Year','Month',"Day"], axis=1)
```